# How to stop chrome bookmarks bar dropdown menu from collapsing when you move an item?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Whenever I want to quickly rearrange some items in the chrome bookmarks bar, the process is very tedious.

Move an item > navigate back down the tree of bookmarks > Move another item > ...

Is there a way of keeping the dropdown open while you move items (without having to open the bookmark manager)?

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: It was filed as a "bug" in 2008, and 10 years later is not fixed yet: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2469 - no words.